# Error in creating a docker container from docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to use docker file for a flask app. I have this docker file(end of file):

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python3 manage.py"]
```

it's been build successfully with the command `sudo docker build -t server .` then I run it with `sudo docker run -dit -p 5000:5000 -t server:latest` but I get :

```
6acfe48c74d96c12eeda2c2cc98e27d2e5478edaa44f2061336102f04cdf54c4
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/python3 manage.py\": stat /usr/bin/python3 manage.py: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Let me know if you need more information. ( I used `which python3` and pasted the PATH and used `ls` and saw `manage.py` exists there)

Comment: Try running it using this command

    `docker run -itd -p 5000:5000 server:{tagname} /bin/bash` 

will you please check your image name and tag name properly ? i think this error is occuring due to the name of image or tag of your docker image !

Comment: After your image is being successfully build, then check your image name and its tag name properly then try running the container from the following command !

Comment: @actually the problem `no such file` is gone, but when I request to 0.0.0.0:5000 I get `read tcp 127.0.0.1:39060->127.0.0.1:5000: read: connection reset by peer`.

Comment: This problably will be a network related issue.

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed I already `EXPOSE 5000` and `-p 5000:5000` is there any other thing I should do?

Comment: one thing i can suggest is that, Comment out `Expose and CMD` both commands from your Docker file.                                                                                                                             
then try to run the container by passing the script in argument like this                               
`docker run -itd -p 5000:5000 -d {image:tag} {your_script}`

Comment: Mount your script inside the container using Volume Mount Docker !

Comment: Yeah , it worked with add script to run command , how can I mount script that I shouldn't use script in `run` command?

Comment: let's say on my base machine there is a script at `/var/www/test.sh` and you want to mount it inside the container at same path, you can do it as follows;
`docker run -itd -v /var/www/test.sh:/var/www/ -p 5000:5000 -d  {image:tag} /var/www/test.sh`

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed Is there any way I can add this to docker file ? or maybe using docker-compose , I just want to run command be a simple one

Comment: Dear, go through the documentation and you will find it.               https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python3 manage.py"]
```

You are directing the system to run exactly that file; but there is no file named `python3 manage.py` in the `/usr/bin` directory.  If you have a separate command and arguments then they need to be two separate things in the CMD listing:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python3", "manage.py"]
```